# How do I make a Java program that draws lines?

Tags: java, draw, lines

What I'm trying to do is make a program that creates four lines. I want it to go through a for loop and each time it loops the lines move closer to eachother. Eventually I want the lines to meet in the center of the box and form a swirl.

The initial positions would start as:

```
line[0].x = 0;          line[0].y = 0;
line[1].x = 0;          line[1].y = boxSize;
line[2].x = boxSize;    line[2].y = boxSize;
line[3].x = boxSize;    line[3].y = 0;
```

To find the next point I would do:

```
line[(i+1)%4].y–line[i].y
```

I'm having trouble with the draw function. How would I implement that into my code?

Answer (score 1):

try using awt

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
                                                   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

Color bg = new Color(242, 242, 242);
g2d.setColor(bg);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
g2d.setColor(Color.red);
g2d.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy);
```

provide you own values of course

Comment: Here's an image of what I want the code to output:                     http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o525/walroid/Javapicture_zps12201eb6.png